# Play / pause flash.display.avm1movie from flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

I am using swfLoader to load external flash movies in my flex/actionscript code. If the loaded swf was made for the newer flash player versions ( I believe 9.0 or more) it loads as a flash.display.MovieClip object which has methods for play/pause and go to frame. However if the loaded swf was made for older flash player (I believe 6.0) then it loads as flash.display.av1movie which doesn't have methods for play/pause. Is there a way I can play / pause the av1movie from my flex code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method: [ForcibleLoader](http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/18/forcibleloader/). It works like this - loads swf as ByteArray, then modifies it and loads result with loadBytes. It sets `as3` flag to `true` and swf version to 9. Be warned, though, that as2 scripts aren't working properly in AVM2, because it has many differences from AVM1. But if you have simple animation, this may work. You'll get MovieClip instead of AVM1Movie, just test it.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.  Try this: http://code.google.com/p/as3-classes/source/browse/trunk/org/lzyy/util/ForcibleLoader.as

Answer (score 1):

Nope , there isn't!

From the docs:

```
  The AVM1Movie object can use methods and properties inherited from the 
  DisplayObject  class (such as x, y, width, and so on). However, no 
  interoperability (such as calling methods or using parameters) 
  between the AVM1Movie object and AVM2 objects is allowed.
```